# Sample Size with Uncertainties

Tags: sample-size, sample, uncertainty

I am looking for the sample size of a relatively abstract problem.

Here is an example to make it more tangible. The plan is to investigate a new type of motorcycle which can react to roadway damages (by e.g. avoiding them automatically) and therefore test the highways of a specific country for damages. At the moment I dont exactly know which road damages the motorcycle and its system reacts to and how many damages there exactly are, but based on experience damages should appear every 5 miles. The mentioned type of motorcycle is not available yet, but I would like to know how many miles I would have to drive to ensure to cover the most critical damages (statistical certainty e.g. 95%).

What would be a appropriate way to calculate the sample size with those uncertainties?

Comment: What will be the outcome of your investigation? The percentage of road damages that the motorcycle avoids?

Comment: How well does the avoiding system work? What needs to be improved?

Comment: In order to determine the sample size, "how well does it work" needs to be quantified. One example is as I suggested "How much percent of the road damages does it avoid?", but there are obviously also other options. After you have chosen how you want to measure "how well does it work", I might be able to further assist you in the sample size determination.

Comment: We can use the percentage of avoided road damages as an outcome.

Another (general) possible result could be "how many road damages are there" and therefore "how big has my sample need to be"

Comment: The sample size determination will have to be based on a number of road damages anyway (e.g. "You need to drive past 200 road damages in order to ..."), therefore the amount of miles you need to drive can only be estimated using "required road damages"x5. As a secondary outcome in the study you could measure the distance between road damages, e.g. "3miles between start and first damage", "5miles between first damage and second damage" etc and analyse this seperately. I will add an answer regarding the computation of the sample size in the next hours.

Comment: Thank you for your help!
We can assume (based on experience) that critical road damages (that the motorcycle cant avoid) appear every 5miles (as a worst case scenario). Of course the more we improve the system the large this distance is going to be (e.g. 15miles between two critical road damages).

If you need the total amount of critical road damages (the ones that the motorcycle cant avoid) we could use the total highway network in USA (50,000miles) which results in 10,000 critical road damages (for the first test with the motorcycle)

Answer (score 1):

Statistically speaking, you want to calculate the required sample size in order to estimate a single proportion ("What's the percentage of road damages that the motorcycle will avoid") with a certain precision ("How exact should the estimation be"), given a certain significance level ("error probability").

The ingredients you need for to calculate the sample size are therefore:

1. Significance level $\alpha$. Usually this is set to $0.05$, but nothing is keeping you from choosing a different value.
2. An initial estimate for the proportion, let's call it $p$. If you happen to have some data from a pilot study or the test ground or just a strong intuition, you can use it. If not, you can set $p=0.5$, because this will results in the biggest sample size and is therefore your "worst-case-scenario".
3. The precision $\delta$. This will determine how precise your estimate of the proportion will be, i.e. how long the width of the confidence interval will be.

The formula to calculate the required sample size is given by

$n \geq (\frac{Q^{N(0,1)}(1-\frac{\alpha}{2})}{\delta})^2*p*(1-p)$,

where $Q^{N(0,1)}(1-\frac{\alpha}{2})$ denotes the $1-\frac{\alpha}{2}$ quantile of the standard normal distribution.

---

I will present one scenario here and aid you with the interpretation.

Assume you set $\alpha=0.05$, meaning you allow for $5$% error probability, $p=0.5$, since you have no idea about how the motorcycle will perform and $\delta = 0.015$, meaning you want to know the percentage of road damages that it avoids within $3$%.

Then the above formula yields $n\geq 4269$.

This means: If you drive the motorcycle around until you encountered $4269$ road damages and record for each road damage, whether or not the motorcycle avoided it, you will be able to estimate the total (=theoretical) proportion that the motorcycle avoides with a precision of at least $3$% while having an "error probability" of $5$%.

I deliberately wrote "a precision of at least $3$%", because the further away the total proportion is from $0.5$, the more precise your estimation will be.

The results that you will get after your study will be a confidence interval, which might look like this: $[0.44; 0.47]$. This would be interpreted (roughly) as "There is a $95$% chance that the true proportion of road damages that the motorcycle avoids is between $44$% and $47$%".

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
Do you take into account if I investigate the road damages in USA (total amount of highway miles 50,000) or UK (2,500 total highway miles)?

Comment: No I did not - the sample size can say nothing about the actual miles you need to drive. At most you can multiply the number by e.g. 5 to get an estimate of how many miles it will amount to. Ultimately it's about the amount of road damages that you encountered. Whether you encounter them in the US in 10,000 miles or in the UK in 15,000 miles or in Central Africa in 1,000 miles does not matter.

Comment: If I was able to answer your question, I kindly ask for an upvote and my answer to be accepted. If you have more questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: I dont totally understand the country issue. At the end of the day 
I want to investigate how my motorcycle works in the US, UK or Central Africa. 
- So if USA has 50,000 total highway miles and UK just 2,500 miles, I feel like my sample size in the US would have to be way bigger then UK. (after 2,500 miles in the UK Ive seen every road damage, therefore I'd perfectly know how my motorcycle works at every corner... but after 2,500 miles in the US I probably have seen just a very small portion

Comment: - road damages directly depend on the investigated country (road maintenance, road technology, and so on). Therefore i need to take into account where I'm investigating

- last thing: If I want to know the percentage of road damage in the specific country (and not primarily how well the system works) I feel like the total highway network (US 50000 - UK 2500 miles) does matter

Comment: Well, statistically it does not. If the question of your study is "What percentage of road damages does my motorcycle avoid", then it only matters that you encounter a certain amount of road damages, as I explained above. How well a bike works in a particular country will be a direct result of how many damages it avoids, i.e. don't use it in Central Africa.

If, however, your research question is a different one and potentially more complex, like you want to see what road damages does it avoid etc, then (given you have no previous data) you cannot do a formal sample size calculation.

Comment: Obviously you could have a more complex model like you are trying to model whether or not the bike avoids a road damage with respect to -)type of the road damage, -)outside temperature, -)weather, etc. etc. 
But then 1) you cannot do a formal sample size calculation and 2) still there is not "country-effect", since the "country-effect" is a direct results of other parameters like the weather, outside temperature, type of road damages predominant in a certain country and so on.

Comment: What about using the total highway network 50,000 miles as the total size (population size) and the distribution of 1/5 miles (approx. distance between two critical road damages). Could I use this numbers to calculate my sample size? Simple Sampe calculator somehow dont wanna know more then this (together with confidence level and error)

Comment: That makes no sense for your research question, since you are not trying to assess how good the US highways are, but how well your motorcycle performs. And theoretically the US have unlimited highway miles, because you could drive the same highway twice and not only once (which literally everybody will do). As I wrote above, if you use the estimation of one road damage per 5 miles and want to estimate how many miles you need to drive, then just multiply the required road damages by 5. In my answer this would lead to 4269x5=21345 miles that you need to drive.

Comment: I want to use the motorcycle in the US and avoid as many road damages as possible. Therefore I want to experience in the design phase all road damages (ideally but not reasonable) or most of them (as a sample).

Comment: With your calculation I would drive 22,000 miles in the US and be positive, that my motorcylce and system works well in avoiding road damages. What if I would go to the UK (maybe there are different road damages that we've never experienced and that our motorcycle cant avoid yet) do we have to drive another 22,000 miles (which means experience every UK highway mile almost 10 times)

Comment: No, you cannot be sure after 22,000 miles in the US that the motorcycle works well (it seems we have been going in circles; my first comment to your question was that you need to quantify "working well"). You will, however, be pretty sure on how well it works (see my answer on the intrepretation). And as mentioned above: If you want to make a more complex model involving type of road damages, weather, possibly left-lane traffic vs right-lane traffic, etc, there is no way to do a formal sample size calculation if you have no previous information.

Comment: what previous information would you need?

Comment: Firstly, and most importantly, you would have to know what exactely you want to do. And "Testing how well the motorcycle works" is not knowing what exactely you want to do. Then you need to have a lot of previous information about e.g. how do you expect the bike to work in rain. After that a formal sample size calculation/power analysis might be possible, depending on all the above parameters. TBH though I don't feel that this is still in the scope of this question and requires thorough thinking and planning. Ideally you should consult a statistician and involve him in the ongoing study.